# How to show dialog background color on full screen with statusbar and navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

How can i change color of statusbar and navigation bar when dialog box show in flutter i already try the SystemChrome.setSystemUiOverlay is there any other method available to change the color of statusbar and navigation bar in flutter

Here i Post picture to [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg6ZT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll work for you.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns

A package can help you to change your flutter app's statusbar's color or navigationbar's color programmatically.

This is a fork of the original package flutter_statusbarcolor migrated to support null-safety.